# Suffire à vs. suffire pour

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes

[Voici une citation](http://www.cultivonsnous.fr/c/citations/citations-de-serguei-vassilievitch-rachmaninov/) du compositeur Rachmaninoff :

> *La musique suffit pour une existence, mais une existence ne suffit pas à la musique.*

Qu'elle est la différence entre "suffire à" et "suffire pour" ? Est-ce qu'on peut aussi dire "La musique suffit à une existence" ou "une existence ne suffit pas pour la musique" ?

[Le dictionnaire Collins dit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/suffire) :

> suffire à qn : *to be enough for sb*
>
> suffire pour qch : *to be enough for sth*

Cela suggère que la différence se trouve dans <s>l'objet</s> le complément, si c'est une personne (quelqu'un) ou une chose (quelque chose). Cependant, bien que dans la citation "la musique" ne soit pas vraiment une personne, il a quand même utilisé "suffit à".

(S'il y a des erreurs grammaticales dans ma question, dites-le-moi s'il vous plaît !)

Comment: Je dirais qu'en général, c'est les formes les plus communes, mais ça ne veut pas dire qu'on est limité à ces deux formes. Dans ce contexte, les deux fonctionnent.

Comment: Merci jilliagre et LPH d'avoir corrigé mes erreurs !

Answer (score 3):

> La musique suffit pour une existence.

La musique suffit à combler un être humain pour toute sa vie.

> Une existence ne suffit pas à la musique.

La musique transcende la vie. La musique survit aux hommes.

Si on intervertit les prépositions, on arrive quand même à leur trouver une justification :

> La musique suffit à une existence

Le sens est globalement le même, la musique suffit à satisfaire l'homme durant sa vie.

> une existence ne suffit pas pour la musique (c'est la phrase la moins naturelle des quatre)

Pour la musique, c'est à dire du point de vue de la musique, une existence (une vie) ne suffit pas.

Le Collins donne deux cas d'usage courants mais ça ne signifie pas qu'il n'y en a pas d'autres.

En voici un où le sens peut légèrement varier, mais il y a sûrement une part de subjectivité :

> Ça suffit à mon fils. (il l'a, il en est content, il ne demande pas plus)

> Ça suffit pour mon fils. (il ne l'a pas encore et il s'en contentera ou il l'a et on n'a pas besoin de lui en donner plus)

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Pardon, je comprends bien le sens de la citation, la traduction anglaise est assez connu. Ma question porte sur l'usage des prépositions "à" et "pour." Par exemple, est-ce que les sens que vous avez écrits changent si on échange "suffit à" et "suffit pour" dans la citation?

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour vos explications supplémentaires !

Answer (score 1):

Le dictionnaire Collins n'entre pas trop dans les détails ; c'est la raison de l'apparente incohérence.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suffire)) **A. − Constituer à soi seul le facteur déterminant pour que soit obtenu l'effet que l'on constate ou le résultat que l'on attend.**
>
> 1. [**Le suj. est un animé ou ce qui lui est propre**]
>    **a)**  […]
>    **b)** **Qqn suffit à + subst**
>    ♦︎ Dans le tourbillon de tant de jouissances, le cœur et les yeux ne peuvent suffire à la multitude des sensations.  (Volney, Ruines, 1791, p. 15)

> 2. [**Le suj. appartient au domaine de l'inanimé**]
>    **a) Qqc. suffit à/pour**
>    […]
>    − **Qqc. suffit pour + subst**
>    ♦︎ Une moindre calamité n'aurait pas suffi pour les desseins de Dieu. (Baudel., Paradis artif., 1860, p. 459)

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, le verbe est le même et sa définition est donnée ci-dessus au « **A** ». « L'effet que l'on constate ou le résultat que l'on attend » n'est pas nécessairement exprimé mais peut découler de ce qui est exprimé par le complément de la préposition lorsque c'est un substantif.  Selon les prépositions employées, divers éléments sont mis en rapport.

**Une existence ne suffit pas à la musique** (**A.1.**) L'existence est qqc de propre à un animé (comme les yeux, le cœur, dans l'exemple est propre aux animés que sont les humains) ; remarquer que le complément n'est pas nécessairement un animé, c'est seulement *un* substantif. Donc, « une existence [suffit/ne suffit pas] à la musique » est correct. On doit comprendre par « musique » non pas les arrangements de notes, mais quelque chose de plus ; il s'agit de la réalisation suffisamment complète de la musique,  l'effet que l'on attend c'est cela.

**La musique suffit pour une existence** (**A.2.**) Dans ce cas encore, le substantif est quelconque.

Ce que cette phrase signifie, c'est que l'occupation qui consiste à étudier la musique et à en créer suffit à remplir la vie professionnelle de quelqu'un, mais que toute une vie d'efforts dans le domaine de la création musicale n'est pas suffisante pour faire ce que l'on peut faire  de meilleur en matière de création musicale.

Answer (score 1):

La différence entre les 2 formulations tient dans la portée, la dimension. La différence grammaticale est assez nuancée, et ce type d'expression la met justement en avant.

Pour l'illustrer, je prendrai un exemple. Imaginez que vous ayez un objectif très important dans votre vie, comme obtenir un job, réussir un concours, rencontrer, voire épouser une femme... que diriez-vous de cet objectif ? Il y a 2 façons de formuler ce qu'il représente :

- "Atteindre cet objectif suffit à mon bonheur" : cela signifie que cela me comblerait, me rendrait très heureux, serait une belle réussite
- "Atteindre cet objectif suffit pour que je sois heureux" : les francophones comprendront de suite le côté très objectif, terre à terre, pragmatique, sans affect. Pour que je sois heureux, il me faut cet objectif. Presque sous entendu : ni plus ni moins. Or, dans la vie, ce n'est évidemment pas le cas, car le bonheur se résume rarement à l'atteinte d'un objectif (même s'il peut y contribuer, pour reprendre une citation)

A l'inverse, si je vous dis : "une bonne pelle suffit pour creuser un trou", je pense que personne ne me contredira. Et même s'il serait difficile de faire un trou pour une piscine, cela reste vrai. Par contre, personne ne dirait : "Une bonne pelle suffit à creuser un trou", car cela reste quelque chose de précis et concret.